# Getting top level exception on using //cf flag in ncover to exclude properties from Coverage reports

Tags: ncover

I am using //cf flag to exclude properties from the ncover coverage report like

//cf "*get_*":Method   but i am getting error 2000 " top level exception" Unrecognised comandline option cf.

Please suggest what to do.

Thanks
priya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used these filters on one of my test projects: //cf "BusinessObjects*":Assembly:False:True //cf "get":Method //cf "set":Method

Only BusinessObjects was included, and all my get and set methods were excluded. Hopefully, that modified wildcard syntax will work as you expect. I was also successful with regex pattern 'get.*'